# Laravel 5.4 form validation

Tags: laravel

I need a form validation in Laravel 5.4

if Database table column dose not exist value of text field of form pass custom error massage to errors() that available in all views.

I'm using web routing.

Thank you,

Comment: Step 1: [Read the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#introduction). Step 2: Write some code.

Answer (score 1):

The below validation with do the job.

```
'some_form_field' => 'exists:database_table_name,column_name'
```